# scalar product - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I've been studying linear algebra, then I've faced with this question:

> Three vectors $p$, $q$, and $r$ sum to a zero vector and have the magnitude of $10$, $11$, and $15$, respectively. Determine the value of $p\cdot q + q\cdot r + r\cdot p$.

I came to the following conclusions:

**p + q + r = 0 (obvious)**

The following system of equations (obvious too):

**xp + xq +xr = 0**

**yp + yq +yr = 0**

**zp + zq +zr = 0**

And if I replace the dot products of the exercise, I have:

**10.11.cos(teta1) + 11.15.cos(teta2) + 15.10.cos(teta3)**

teta1 = angle between p and q;

teta2 = angle between q and r;

teta3 = angle between r and p.

It seems to me that the last equation is necessary, since the exercise supplies the module values.
However, I don't see how to relate them to achieve a solution.
Could you help me?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Please show us the work you've done up to that point, and what you don't understand, specifically.

Comment: @amWhy I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier: since$$(p+q+r)^2=(p+q+r)\cdot(p+q+r)=p^2+q^2+r^2+2(p\cdot q+q\cdot r+r\cdot p),$$ you want$$\tfrac12((p+q+r)^2-p^2-q^2-r^2)=-\frac12(10^2+11^2+15^2)=-223.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't get your logic.
Can you explain with more details?

Comment: @AndréMachoski See edit.